# Change in sudoers does not take effect. Ubuntu 16.10 fresh install + one line.

Tags: sudo, 16.10, visudo

Trying to remove password on sudo. My current sudoers file:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"


root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL


vidar ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I quit, open new terminal (or even reboot), but password is still required for sudo. User is member of sudo group.

What can possibly be happening?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to reboot for the change to take effect.

You are missing the `:ALL` part of the entry.

**Change from:**

```
vidar ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

**change to:**

```
vidar ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: It's now working fine with the attached sudoers file . Probably human error of some kind.

Answer (score 3):

The order of the entries in the `sudoers` file is important. You should also check the directory `/etc/sudoers.d`, because entries on this directory may be overwriting what you trying to do on `sudoers`.

You can also check the `/etc/sudoers.d/README` for more information.

Comment: What do you mean by 'The order of entries is important'?  What needs to be done to achieve what OP wants?

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen if you have the same entry for an user, the last one will take effect. So, it is necessary to check all the content of ``sudoers`` file to see if there are no duplicates. Also, it is necessary to check ``/etc/sudoers.d/`` to see if there are no entries there.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on and complement the answer provided by @Eduardo , the order of the entries in the `sudoers` file is important not only because of possible duplicate entries, but also for group rules that a later group rule may overwrite any previous rules specified for users that belong to the group.

For example, a sudoers file like this

```
# User privilege specification                                                    
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL                                                         
userX   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Members of the admin  group may gain root privileges                             
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL                                                              
                                                                                  
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command                              
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

may have problems  when userX belongs to either `admin` or `sudo` group, as the `NOPASSWD:` rule will be overwritten by rules applied to the `admin` and/or `sudo` groups, thus your `NOPASSWD:` rule will be lost.

So it's safer to put individual user rules in the `sudoers.d` directory since those will be loaded later than the default group rules.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.
Adding my changes in /etc/sudoers.d/anotherfile  made it work.

visusdo will open /etc/sudoers for editing but in my case i also added /etc/sudoers.d/anotherfile as the changes in sudoers file were not enabled.

Comment: What changes? This is not a complete answer.